# Print posts category or tag as a formatted journal

Tags: plugins, posts

I was looking for a plugin to allow to choose a post category and print it as a formatted newspaper (full text and at least 2 column with a title).

In other words. I would like to create a printed periodic newsletter with my wordpress posts.

Unfortunately the ones that I found just display two columns at the screen. Even [WP Journal](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wpjournal/) displays a great formatted journal on screen but it renders only one column without formatting when printing. All beauty goes away when printing.

Do you know any plugin that allow me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a specific plugin to achieve columns in print, you can modify how your layout looks when printing using the `print` CSS [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media). You can learn more about this topic [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/).

In case of the WP Journal plugin to print 3 columns of text add this:

```
@media print {
    .cols3 {
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
        -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid silver;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-gap: 20px;
        -moz-column-rule: 1px solid silver;
        column-count: 3;
        column-gap: 20px;
        column-rule: 1px solid #000;
    }
}
```

About how to add custom CSS code to your site read [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-css-to-your-wordpress-site/)